# Property 'push' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

When i'm compile the angular code the compiler show me "Property 'push' does not exist on type 'any[]' " this error. Bellow the .service.ts and .component.ts code respectively.

Service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  readonly userspath = "Development/users/users";
  collectionRef= "Development"
  ref = "Development"
  usersRef="users"

  public usersArray = [];

  constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getUser(){

   return  this.af.database.ref(this.ref).child(this.usersRef)    

 }
}
```

component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  public user = [];
  usersArray = [];
   constructor(
    private userservice:UserService,
    private router: Router
   ) { }

  title = "Employees";
  ngOnInit( ) {
    this.userservice.getUser().on('value',snapshot => {
     snapshot.forEach(data => {
      this.usersArray.push(data.val());
     })

  })
 }
```

VScode show me Property 'push' does not exist on type 'any[]' this error

Comment: declare variable like this : usersArray: any = [];

Comment: add types for all the variables you declare. It is a good practice

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
ngOnInit( ) {
    this.userservice.getUser().on('value',snapshot => {
     this.usersArray = [];
     snapshot.forEach((data:any) => {
      this.usersArray.push(data.val());
     })

  })
```

Comment: define array like this usersArray: any[] = [];